# how check is the json Array available and exist?

Tags: android, json

I'm loading a json array in my app.but i need to know if the json array is exist or not? because if the json array isn't exist, the app will crash.

for example, I have this json:

```
{ 
"music1":
    [
    {
    "art":"",
                 "artist":"",
    "music":"",
     "flag":"",
                 "text":"",
                 "level":""
 }, 
    {
    "art":"",
                 "artist":"",
    "music":"",
    "flag":"",
                 "text":"",
                 "level":""
 },
]
}
```

and I want to know is there any json object named "music1" in my code or not, and then if there was I want to get the json array and show it in a list in my android app.

I'm looking forward a hero that could help me!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To answer your question, you should provide more details about your code, for instance the code snippet which is causing the crash.

Comment: just throw `JSONException e`, it will track if no value corresponding to your array available in json and possibly your app will not crash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wish this explanation would fit in a comment.

Anyway:

```
{ 
"music1":
    [
    {
    "art":"",
                 "artist":"",
    "music":"",
     "flag":"",
                 "text":"",
                 "level":""
 }, 
    {
    "art":"",
                 "artist":"",
    "music":"",
    "flag":"",
                 "text":"",
                 "level":""
 }
]
}
```

Let call the above json object o.
So to check if o has music1, all you need to check is write the following line:

```
if(o.has("music1")){
   JSONArray array= o.getJSONArray("music1");
}
```

Then you extract the objects of the json array :

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
     array.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the availability of field:

```
if(jsonObj.has("music1")){
    //yes
}
```

or this case:

```
JSONArray mJSONArray = jsonObj.optJSONArray("nmusic1");
```

If array is not available mJSONArray will be null