# Populating UI with JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I need help. I'm doing some project for a review and I'm stuck with populating UI with JSON.

Here's the code for JsonUtils.class

```
package com.udacity.sandwichclub.utils;

import com.udacity.sandwichclub.model.Sandwich;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonUtils {

    public static Sandwich parseSandwichJson(String json) {

        try {
            //Root JSONObject Sandwich
            JSONObject jsonSandwich = new JSONObject(json);

            //Sandwich common name and also known as
            JSONObject sandwichName = jsonSandwich.getJSONObject("name");

            //Common name of the sandwich
            String commonName = sandwichName.getString("mainName");

            //Sandwich is also known as
            List<String> alsoKnownAsName = jsonArrayList(jsonSandwich
                    .getJSONArray("alsoKnownAs"));

            //Place of origin of the sandwich
            String placeOfOrigin = jsonSandwich.getString("placeOfOrigin");

            //Description of the sandwich
            String descript = jsonSandwich.getString("description");

            //Image of the sandwich
            String sandwichImg = jsonSandwich.getString("image");

            //Ingredients of the sandwich
            List<String> sandwichIngredients = jsonArrayList(jsonSandwich
                    .getJSONArray("ingredients"));

            //Return object Sandwich
            return new Sandwich(commonName, alsoKnownAsName, placeOfOrigin,
                    descript, sandwichImg, sandwichIngredients);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Method for listing ingredients and also known as names
    public static List<String> jsonArrayList(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        List<String> jsonList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(jsonArray != null) {
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                jsonList.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
            }
        }

        return jsonList;
    }
}
```

and here's detail activity which has to receive JSON data.
DetailActivity.java

```
package com.udacity.sandwichclub;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.udacity.sandwichclub.model.Sandwich;
import com.udacity.sandwichclub.utils.JsonUtils;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "extra_position";
    private static final int DEFAULT_POSITION = -1;

    private Sandwich sandwich;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        ImageView ingredientsIv = findViewById(R.id.image_iv);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent == null) {
            closeOnError();
        }

        int position = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, DEFAULT_POSITION);
        if (position == DEFAULT_POSITION) {
            // EXTRA_POSITION not found in intent
            closeOnError();
            return;
        }

        String[] sandwiches = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sandwich_details);
        String json = sandwiches[position];
        Sandwich sandwich = JsonUtils.parseSandwichJson(json);
        if (sandwich == null) {
            // Sandwich data unavailable
            closeOnError();
            return;
        }

        populateUI();
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(sandwich.getImage())
                .into(ingredientsIv);

        setTitle(sandwich.getMainName());
    }

    private void closeOnError() {
        finish();
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.detail_error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void populateUI() {
        //Populating also known as text with JSON
        TextView alsoKnownAsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.also_known_tv);
        alsoKnownAsText.setText(sandwich.getAlsoKnownAs() + ", ");

        //Populating ingredients text with JSON
        TextView ingredientsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ingredients_tv);
        alsoKnownAsText.setText(sandwich.getIngredients() + ", ");

        //Populating place of origin text with JSON
        TextView placeOfOriginText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.origin_tv);
        placeOfOriginText.setText(sandwich.getPlaceOfOrigin());

        //Populating description text with JSON
        TextView descriptionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_tv);
        descriptionText.setText(sandwich.getDescription());
    }
}
```

So this method populateUI dosen't work for me ... when I click from MainActivity one item it pop's up an toast message that there's no data for that.

This is what Logcat says:

```
02-18 18:56:47.591 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for alsoKnownAs
02-18 18:56:47.591 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
02-18 18:56:47.591 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
02-18 18:56:47.591 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at com.udacity.sandwichclub.utils.JsonUtils.parseSandwichJson(JsonUtils.java:28)
02-18 18:56:47.591 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at com.udacity.sandwichclub.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:42)
02-18 18:56:47.591 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
02-18 18:56:47.591 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
02-18 18:56:47.593 4291-4291/com.udacity.sandwichclub W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: post the log errors

Comment: @ALTegani I've edited the post, take a look.

Comment: Well... Print out your JSON, and tell us if `.getJSONArray("alsoKnownAs"));` should work or not. Hard to help parse something we can't see

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells that your json key is not exist or it is incorrect

Check your key if it is exist then parse it

```
    if(o.has("alsoKnownAs")){
         JSONArray array= o.getJSONArray("alsoKnownAs"); 
     }
```

Comment: Check this https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494539/how-check-is-the-json-array-available-and-exist&ved=2ahUKEwjthsLsirDZAhXEAewKHRljAf0QFjAAegQIExAB&usg=AOvVaw3cbExMeC-uKGtJZzjblJNG

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse the json?

Only with that lines you parse the json string:

```
public static Sandwich parseSandwichJson(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Sandwich sandwich = gson.fromJson(json, Sandwich.class);
}
```

Any way, your problem is because the json that you try to parse hasn't the element "alsoKnownAs"

Use "getJSONArray" method to retrieve a mandatory value. In case that the value can be optional you need use "optJSONArray".

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. You need use "optJSONArray" method to  read the "alsoKnownAs" element

Comment: I found mistake ... the list of aka names was wrongly parsed ... I parsed it on root object instead to object ''name'' ... , now there's some mess I need to repair in UI

Comment: Ok, perfect. Consider the "opt..." methods for other moments.